# How Youtube open 2 JPG with 1 URL

Tags: javascript, php, url, youtube, thumbnails

i was wondering how youtube thumbnails works

[here](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xX8GAFN03qE/hqdefault.jpg?custom=true&w=168&h=94&stc=true&jpg444=true&jpgq=90&sp=67&sigh=xg6X6OpNHiKCfhr8v6Q9bQ1EzY0) is a example thumbnails from random youtube video there is a hqdefault.jpg in url than we see some variables showing the size if we remove or change the variables it will show the bigger image
i can do this using .php file but how youtube doing this using .jpg

Example:
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/xX8GAFN03qE/hqdefault.jpg?custom=true&w=168&h=94&stc=true&jpg444=true&jpgq=90&sp=67&sigh=xg6X6OpNHiKCfhr8v6Q9bQ1EzY0

Comment: this is showing single pic you just pass size to the url. I mean at a time only one image is showing based on the parameter. There may be multiple file to match with the parameter.

Comment: `*.jpg` is a hint, not a restriction. It can lead to a `php` script that generates the jpeg and then feeds the information to the browser with the headers telling it to interpret that data as an `image/jpeg`

Comment: note: this is why you can't trust the internet. When your browser (or email client) fetches my 'smile.gif' image, I collect all the data I can from your browser/client through my PHP script, set up a session and watch all your movements as you keep getting my 'smile.gif' image on each page. All you see is a lovely smiley emoji

Answer (score 0):

You can instruct Apache to redirect all requests to `/thumbnails/*.jpg` to a PHP file, getting the `*` part as a parameter, along with all other parameters from the original URL.

Copy this into your `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/thumbnails/([^.]+\.jpg)$ /some.php?img=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Now, every time you load

`http://example.com/thumbnails/file1.jpg`

you will be actually loading

`http://example.com/some.php?img=file1.jpg`

See [Apache's mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html) docs for more info.